# A better way to filter a column in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python

```
# Selecting all of the Subscriber & Children Tier People 
D = df[df['Member Tier'].str[0] == 'D']
CountD =D[D['Relation'].str[0] == 'M']
= len(CountD)
```

I have a data set where people are classified based on a member tier and a relation, any way to combine these steps into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can you use `groupby`:

```py
count = df.groupby(["Member Tier", "Relation"]).get_group(("D", "M")).shape[0]
```

Here, you're grouping by two columns, and then selecting the group that only has `"Member Tier" == "D"` and `"Relation" == "M"`. Finally, you use shape to obtain the number of rows of that DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like kmundnic above, but another way might be;

```
count = len(df.query("`Member Tier` == 'D' & Relation == 'M'"))
```